# Resulting hash codes of object copied with Ecoreutil.Copier is different from original

Tags: eclipse, modeling, emf, eclipse-emf

I am using `ECoreUtil.Copier` to create a copy of my `EObject`. However, the exact copy is created but with different hash codes.

Why does the hash codes change?

Comment: This is what you would expect if the objects are using the default `hashCode` from `Object` - every object has a different hash code.

Answer (score 1):

The `equals` method and `hashCode` of EObjects are based on the *identity* of the objects. This is required by the [EMF specification](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.11/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/EObject.html). Two different objects must be considered different by `equals`, and should also have different hash codes, even if their members have the same values.

When you copy objects with `ECoreUtil.Copier` the result is new objects, with new identities.

If you want to compare EObjects to find out if they are structurally equivalent – even when they are different objects – then you can use the [`EcoreUtils.equals`](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.11/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/EcoreUtil.html#equals(org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject,%20org.eclipse.emf.ecore.EObject)) method.